# dynamic css selector - Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

I am trying to click on button on a webpage that will take me to a user's email settings. I want to find a css selector based on the username or email address that is on the webpage then click on that username to get into the settings.

The problem is that the css selector has no way to determine the user I want except for the flag called `data-testuserid=` that holds the email address.

Here is what the full element looks like for the test email I am trying to access:

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCurrentTab_ctlUserList_ctlUserList_rptList_ctl19_ctlRowContent__lnkUser2" class="linkMild" data-testuserid="testmuser@AlloySystems.com" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctlCurrentTab$ctlUserList$ctlUserList$rptList$ctl19$ctlRowContent$_lnkUser2&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">test user</a>
```

Here is the css selector that comes out if you copy it from chrome by right clicking on the element and choosing **copy selector**:

```
#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCurrentTab_ctlUserList_ctlUserList_rptList_ctl19_ctlRowContent__lnkUser2
```

noticed the `ct119`? That is the exact place on the website where that email button exists, but what if I want to search for someone else? How can I got about creating a css selector that would include the email or alias?

Here is a picture of the issue:
[image]

**I do have a work around for now but its not good** - For now, I use the search bar to search for the email I want so it shows up in the list. The problem is the website is trash and sometimes the webpage will tend to freeze and get stuck for now reason. I refresh fixes the issue but I wanted to get around that issue by exact clicking on the css selector of the email address I want.

I hope that makes sense. Thank you everyone.

**Update**

I tried the suggestion that @Strik3r propsed but it didn't work for me. (I unless I typed it wrong.)

Here is the code so far:

```
def reset_email():
    time.sleep(1)
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser_options.browser, 15)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ("//a[@data-testuserid="+email_selection_only.email_select+"]"))))
    im_defaultpolicy = browser_options.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-testuserid="+email_selection_only.email_select+"]") #ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctlCurrentTab_ctlUserList_ctlSearchOptions_txtSearch
    im_defaultpolicy.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Here is the result:

```
line 147, in reset_email
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ("//a[@data-testuserid="+email_selection_only.email_select+"]"))))
  File "/home/tech/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ("//a[@data-testuserid="+email_selection_only.email_select+"]"))))
```

Try

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ("//a[@data-testuserid='+email_selection_only.email_select+']"))))
```

The outer string enclosed with `"` while inner string is enclosed with `'` or vise versa.
But if you are using `"` in both cases Python interprets it as 2 strings

Comment: Helped me get the answer that worked for me. At first it wasn't working but then I changed it to: `('//a[@data-testuserid="'+email_selection_only.email_select+'"]')`. I want to give the answer to both you and @Strik3r as both of you helped me to the answer I needed.

Comment: Well, you can upvote both answers, as I see you did, thanks! And accept the answer that helped more or something like this. For me it's Ok if you accept the second answer if you feel that will be the right thing

Comment: I will give you the answer since you replied back and yours helped me think. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to try ?

```
//a[@data-testuserid='<value>']
```

My understanding is that "**data-testuserid**" is an attribute of the dom element so you should be able to use it in an xpath.

Comment: No luck unfortunately. I tried `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ("//a[@data-testuserid="+email_selection_only.email_select+"]"))))` and it wasn't able to find it. I will update my post to reflect the new work I tried.

Comment: @mentalnoob can you try to see in the browser if you're able to find the element with that xpath ?

Comment: I was able to get it to work using `('//a[@data-testuserid="'+email_selection_only.email_select+'"]')` This is tough because I want to give you and @Prophet the answer. You helped me with the format of how the structure of the element I am trying to look for should look like (`//a[@data-testuserid='<value>']`). @Prophet helped me try some different string formatting to make sure I was getting my email variable into the code correctly. I will wait on this for a little and then give one of you guys the answer.